# newly planted emerald cedars dying from the top tip branches

Tags: cedar

[image]15 5 feet slim tall cedars were planted in late September in GTA, The top branch tips began withering and dying. 15 local grown cedars with much big and heavier root balls are planted together without issues at exact same conditions. What are the causes for the dying tips and how to rescue them? I applied triple mix on the bottom and compost around the root, with saturated root rescue liquid. and watered them 2 to 3 times a week to keep the root soil damp. No more measures I can do. I appreciate advice on cause of the issue and means to take. Attached are pictures. Thank you.